# Magento join customer collection with customer address

Tags: magento-1.9, php, module, query, customer-address

In Magento i want to search the customer with the address(state,city,zipcode), can you explain to me how to the achieve that.

### The customer collection query

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect(array('userid','firstname','lastname','profile_image','specialist','latitude','free_consult','longitude'));
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('group_id',Federallawyer_Customer_Helper_Data::LAWYER);
```

also my shipping and billing address is same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()
            ->joinAttribute('billing_postcode', 'customer_address/postcode', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_city', 'customer_address/city', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_region', 'customer_address/region', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->addFieldToFilter('billing_postcode','123456') // replace with your post code
            ->addFieldToFilter('billing_city','test') // replace with your city
            ->addFieldToFilter('billing_region','test') // replace with your region
```