# Magento 2 joining customers collection with their billing address

Tags: magento2

I'm trying to pull a customers collection but i need to join it to their billing address details to add filters.

The only info i can find so far seems to be for Magento 1, such as this: [Magento join customer collection with customer address](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/74503/magento-join-customer-collection-with-customer-address)

I have tried similar but joinAttribute() doesn't seem to be present in Magento 2, all i get is join() which expects me to give it the table name, so for example i have this:

```
/** @var AbstractCollection $customers */
        $customers = $this->customerCollection->getCollection()
            ->setCurPage($page)
            ->setPageSize($pageSize)
            ->setOrder($orderBy,$order);
```

I'm not sure how to now join this to their billing address since it's across multiple tables, do i need to join all the relevant tables or is there another way in magento to do it?

I have tried the following but i can an error saying **"The "billing_telephone" attribute name is invalid. Reset the name and try again."**

```
$customers->getSelect()->joinLeft(
            ['address'=>'customer_address_entity'],
            'e.default_billing = address.entity_id'
        );

        $customers->addFilterToMap('billing_telephone','address.telephone');

        $customers->addFieldToFilter('billing_telephone',[
            'like'=>'%077%'
        ]);
```

**UPDATE**

I have tried to change things a little but it's not working, so i am injecting "use Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\Collection" for the collection

I then start my query:

```
$customers = $this->customerCollection->setCurPage($page)
            ->setPageSize($pageSize)
            ->setOrder($orderBy,$order);
```

I then add the join:

```
$customers->getSelect()->joinLeft(
            ['billing_address'=>'customer_address_entity'],
            'e.default_billing = billing_address.entity_id',
            ['*']
        );
```

Now this all works, i then add the field to the filters:

```
$customers->addFieldToFilter('billing_address.telephone',[
            'eq'=>'00000'
        ]);
```

This is where the problem happens, it says: **"The "billing_address.telephone" attribute name is invalid. Reset the name and try again."**

Answer (score 0):

Try below code and check.

```
$customerCollection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
    ['billing_address' => $customerCollection->getTable('customer_address_entity')],
    'billing_address.parent_id = main_table.entity_id',
    ['billing_address_id' => 'billing_address.entity_id', 'billing_firstname' => 'billing_address.firstname', 'billing_lastname' => 'billing_address.lastname', 'billing_street' => 'billing_address.street', 'billing_city' => 'billing_address.city', 'billing_region' => 'billing_address.region', 'billing_postcode' => 'billing_address.postcode', 'billing_telephone' => 'billing_address.telephone', 'billing_country_id' => 'billing_address.country_id']
);

foreach ($customerCollection as $customer) {
    echo $customer->getFirstname() . ' ' . $customer->getLastname() . '<br>';
    echo $customer->getBillingFirstname() . ' ' . $customer->getBillingLastname() . '<br>';
    echo $customer->getBillingStreet() . '<br>';
    echo $customer->getBillingCity() . ' ' . $customer->getBillingRegion() . ' ' . $customer->getBillingPostcode() . '<br>';
    echo $customer->getBillingTelephone() . '<br>';
    echo $customer->getBillingCountryId() . '<br><br>';
}
```

This code will join the customer collection with the **`customer_address_entity`** table on the **`parent_id`** column, and retrieve the billing address details for each customer. You can then access the billing address details using the **`getBilling*()`** methods on the customer object.

**`UPDATE`**

```
$customerCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\Collection');
$billingAddressTable = $customerCollection->getTable('customer_address_entity');

$customerCollection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
    ['billing_address' => $billingAddressTable],
    'main_table.default_billing = billing_address.entity_id',
    ['*']
);
```

Then, to filter the collection by a specific code, you can use the following code:

```
$customerCollection->addFieldToFilter('billing_address.postcode', array('eq' => $code));
```

Let me know if any query.

**`THANKS.`**

Comment: Thanks but the issue isn’t selecting the fields, it’s filtering the query by one of the joined fields as per the update to my question

Comment: You means you getting issue filtering not working after join both table right?

Comment: Yeh look at the last bit of my post I try to add the field in the join to the filter map but gives me a weird error. I have bolded the error message in my post for you

Comment: Okay, check my updated answer.

Comment: Apologies for the delay, let me try some things with what you've said in mind, i will then report back

Comment: It doesn't work, i have updated my question under UPDATE to show

Comment: Turns out i can just use getSelect()->where()